# how can we get the Current UserName instead of LoginName using calculated column in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

using [Me] as formula in column gives me current user login name. help me out if we can get the user name instead of login name.

Comment: for example, you have ntnet\hardikk and you want hardik.k ? please explain

Comment: i want it as my full name.                              i.e: SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name

Comment: means Hardik Kothari ?

Comment: you have to use event receiver only, or use Created by column.

Comment: the created by column cannot be used since I have used SPRunWithElevatedPrivileges in my custom code. anyways if you get any OOTB way to store UserName please update me. Thanks Varun Verma! :)